# Where is the source for NVIDIA's "GPL Shim"?

Tags: nvidia

Apparently NVidia connects their (proprietary) driver to the Linux kernel via a GPL-Licensed "shim" intended to protect their driver from falling under the GPL.

Where is the source code for this shim available?

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed “shims” between the proprietary components of the various NVIDIA kernel modules, and the kernel. These shims are provided as source code with each [installer release](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/), but they are not GPL-licensed. They are provided because modules need to be rebuilt for every kernel. The build checks that none of the symbols used are marked as being exported only to GPL modules...

The `nvidia-uvm` module does advertise itself as being “dual MIT/GPL” licensed, but there is no explicit licensing statement referencing the GPL, only the MIT license. [The installer](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvidia-installer/) and [the settings program](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvidia-settings/) are available under the GPL.